# Import detection error with neovim-lsp and tsserver

Tags: reactjs, typescript, neovim, language-server-protocol, typescript-language-server

I recently installed typescript-language-server with neovim-lsp to code my react project, but neovim does not detect shortest module import.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTNVe.png)

Neovim : 0.8.0 + nvChad

My LSP configuration :

```lua
local present, lspconfig = pcall(require, "lspconfig")

if not present then
  return
end

require("base46").load_highlight "lsp"
require "nvchad_ui.lsp"

local M = {}
local utils = require "core.utils"

-- export on_attach & capabilities for custom lspconfigs

M.on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  client.server_capabilities.documentFormattingProvider = false
  client.server_capabilities.documentRangeFormattingProvider = false

  utils.load_mappings("lspconfig", { buffer = bufnr })

  if client.server_capabilities.signatureHelpProvider then
    require("nvchad_ui.signature").setup(client)
  end
end

M.capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()

M.capabilities.textDocument.completion.completionItem = {
  documentationFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" },
  snippetSupport = true,
  preselectSupport = true,
  insertReplaceSupport = true,
  labelDetailsSupport = true,
  deprecatedSupport = true,
  commitCharactersSupport = true,
  tagSupport = { valueSet = { 1 } },
  resolveSupport = {
    properties = {
      "documentation",
      "detail",
      "additionalTextEdits",
    },
  },
}

lspconfig.sumneko_lua.setup {
  on_attach = M.on_attach,
  capabilities = M.capabilities,

  settings = {
    Lua = {
      diagnostics = {
        globals = { "vim" },
      },
      workspace = {
        library = {
          [vim.fn.expand "$VIMRUNTIME/lua"] = true,
          [vim.fn.expand "$VIMRUNTIME/lua/vim/lsp"] = true,
        },
        maxPreload = 100000,
        preloadFileSize = 10000,
      },
    },
  },
}

return M
```

```lua
local on_attach = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").on_attach
local capabilities = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").capabilities

local lspconfig = require "lspconfig"
local servers = {
  "html",
  "intelephense",
  "solargraph",
  "cssls",
  "jsonls",
  "tsserver",
  "denols"
}

for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end
```

I use default tsserver configuration :

https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#tsserver

In my react Project, I use Vite react-ts template with default configuration :

tsconfg.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

what to do so that my configuration is correct and that the imports are correctly detected ?

Thank you

I think it's a configuration problem, I tried a lot of things, but I admit I was quickly wide.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, there was a conflict between tsserver and denols, I deactivated denols given that I am in a node project.

```lua
local on_attach = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").on_attach
local capabilities = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").capabilities

local lspconfig = require "lspconfig"
local servers = {
  "html",
  "intelephense",
  "solargraph",
  "cssls",
  "jsonls",
  "tsserver",
  -- "denols",
  "tailwindcss"
}

for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use both you can set them to load based on the files in the parent dir. Add this under your for loop and remove `"denols"` from your `servers` map.

```
lspconfig.denols.setup {
  root_dir = lspconfig.util.root_pattern("deno.json", "deno.jsonc"),
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities
}
```

If you want you can also do something similar for the typescript lsp (`tsserver`)

```
lspconfig.tsserver.setup{
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  root_dir = lspcofig.util.root_pattern("package.json", "tsconfig.json", "jsconfig.json")
}
```

This should help resolve the conflicts when using both, just make sure that when you are using Deno you have a `deno.json` or `deno.jsonc` in the root dir for the lsp to work correctly.